# Copy/upload file from webserver to standalone mac

Tags: php, macos

How can i copy a file/directory with PHP to a MAC machine?

So from

/home/domain/file/file.jpg

to

standalone macmachine  directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
copy('/Your/Path/From', '/Your/Path/To');

//OR

copy('http://example.com/your_path', '/Your/Path/To');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php copy function. read the following article.

[function.copy.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

for example:

```
<?php 
    copy('/Your/Path/From', '/Your/Path/To');

    //OR

    copy('http://example.com/your_path', '/Your/Path/To');
```

Comment: @Ahref, How does this script know where to put it? The machine is standalone connected to the internet.

Comment: You can change /Your/Path/To to local patch but your web server should have write access to your directory .

Comment: Maybe i am thinking to hard. I want to copy a file form http://www.domain.com/fil.jpg to my local mac osx. How does the script know to where to copy it?